# google play services depends on exact version 22.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, barcode-scanner

i tried to add the dependency for qr code scanner

upon implementing this dependency i'm getting

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.1'
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[22.0.
0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.1 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-commo
n@[22.0.0], but firebase-ml-common version was 22.0.1.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@{strictly 24.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common@{strictly 22.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model@{strictly 16.0.1}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model@16.0.1
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@24.0.1

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[22.0.
0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.1 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-commo
n@[22.0.0], but firebase-ml-common version was 22.0.1.
```

Also,

gradle and google services version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

and gradle wrapper properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show all of the dependencies in you build.gradle.  You should make sure they are all up to date as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this plugin

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.1'
```

and refer this link add qr code scanner

```
https://www.javatpoint.com/android-qr-code-or-bar-code-scanner
```

to ease

```
package com.tvastr.mvvmarchitecture;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcode;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ScannedBarcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    TextView txtBarcodeValue;
    private BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    private CameraSource cameraSource;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 201;
    Button btnAction;
    String intentData = "";
    boolean isEmail = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanned_barcode);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        txtBarcodeValue = findViewById(R.id.txtBarcodeValue);
        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        btnAction = findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
        btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (intentData.length() > 0) {
                    Log.d("log", "intentData email : " + intentData);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void initialiseDetectorsAndSources() {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Barcode scanner started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build();

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1920, 1080)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true) //you should add this feature
                .build();

        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this, new
                            String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "To prevent memory leaks barcode scanner has been stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                    txtBarcodeValue.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if (barcodes.valueAt(0).email != null) {
                                txtBarcodeValue.removeCallbacks(null);
                                intentData = barcodes.valueAt(0).email.address;
                                txtBarcodeValue.setText(intentData);
                                isEmail = true;
                                btnAction.setText("ADD CONTENT TO THE MAIL");
                            } else {
                                isEmail = false;
                                btnAction.setText("LAUNCH URL");
                                intentData = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                                txtBarcodeValue.setText(intentData);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cameraSource.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initialiseDetectorsAndSources();
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnAction"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBarcodeValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="No Barcode Detected"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="ADD CONTENT IN THE MAIL" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i found that the plugin itself is the problem. i don't know how google developers released a buggy plugin and even wrote document on that. But my question is why that plugin is for ?

Answer (score 1):

Change from this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.1'
```

To this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-object-detection-model:19.0.3'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.1'
```